# window onbeforeunload event triggering logout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, window, onbeforeunload

I have come across many answers on Stack Overflow that state how JavaScript cannot detect when a browser is closed. For the most part, that is true, but I have found the code below seems to be able to detect the browser closing.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "logout.php"
  });
}
```

In a perfect world, the user will either log themselves out, or be in idle long enough to be automatically logged out, but that's not always the case.

So I use the above code to call the logout.php script when the user closes the browser.

Here is my problem: when navigating through my site, it seems always at random, the above script is called and the user, of course, is logged out.

I could navigate to one page or back and forth through multiple pages before it happens. Sometimes it gets called immediately when logging in, and I cannot even get into the site.

I cannot figure out why this happens, especially at random.

### Edit

Adding the logout.php script:

```
<?php
  include ('include/sessions.php'); 
  $update = "UPDATE users SET lastlogoutdate = NOW(), currentlyloggedin = 'N' WHERE username = '$username'";
  $updateQuery = mysqli_query($dbc, $update);

  session_destroy();
  header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

Comment: How does `logout.php` actually perform a logout? Is it clearing a cookie or is it more than that? `onbeforeunload` should get called anytime a navigation occurs.

Comment: @phuzi - I'm not using cookies.  I included the logout.php script above.

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not clear the cookie client side? `onbeforeunload` will be called whenever you leave the current document, not matter if it is by using the back or forward or close button. If `logout.php` is called depends on the network latency and is highly unreliable.

Comment: Perhaps I need to rethink/redo my login script and begin using cookies.

Comment: `session_start` uses a session cookie by default which would only normally get removed when the browser is closed not when navigating to another site. `onbeforeunload` __should__ always get fired on page navigation but on past experience cannot be guaranteed to work.

Comment: @phuzi - Explains why I'm being logged out randomly.

Comment: @phuzi even if `onbeforeunload` is called every time it does not guarantee that the Ajax call reaches the server. The code in the `onbeforeunload` must not be able to hinder the user from leaving the page. So an ajax call is not guaranteed to be executed.

Comment: @t.niese yep, which is why I don't think using `onbeforeunload` is the answer.

Comment: Is there a reason you need/want a user to be logged out in this fashion?

Comment: @phuzi - Well, I have a script that logs the user out after 20 minutes of inactivity.  Of course I also have a manual button that the user can click to log out.  I'm simply trying to catch the times the user closes out the browser without manually logging out.  If you'll notice in the logout script, there is a 'currentlyloggedin' value which gets set to 'N' when they log out.  However, if I don't include the browser close check, the user will appear logged in even when they are not.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @JohnBeasley that makes sense and technically they are still logged in so appearing to be logged in is correct. The cookie exists and the session still exists if they revisit your site they won't have to log in again either.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's suggestions.  Are there any other suggestions that can be offered?

Comment: But is it really a problem that a user that closes the window is marked as online for the next 20min?

Comment: @t.niese - The inactivity logout only works if they are actually on the page though inactive for 20 minutes.  If I do not use the code above and they close the browser before the inactivity kicks in, the database will not update their logged in status to 'N', and they will continue to look as if they are still logged in.  But I also cannot use the code above because it randomly logs me out.  I think the appropriate metaphor for this problem would be "I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place."

Comment: The inactivity logout is something you would do server side. There are some many situation that you miss otherwise like: internet connection was lost, the pc/laptop/tablet was send to sleep mode without the browser being closed, a crash of the pc/laptop/tablet, ... . So the lifetime of the session has to be define server side and for each connect from the client to the server the session can be prolonged.

Answer (score -1):

This statements Maye be helpful for you or for some one

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function(){
 if(event.clientX <=0 || event.clientY <=0)
 {
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "logout.php"
 });
  }
  }
```

So log out happens only if user click [X] Button

Comment: You should explain why this solves the problem. Because it looks like a really unreliable check.

Comment: I just finished testing.  Unfortunately, when I close the browser, it does not call the logout.php script and update the table.

Comment: Above I included a decision making to identify user click close button or not. Other wise in each unload situation your Ajax call triggers

Comment: But why should that help to detect the click on the close button. The location of the close button is not standardized. And closing can also be done using the keyboard.

Comment: Think this has more issues than the question has.